# Определение pure virtual function

Tags: c++, ооп, virtual

Недавно обнаружил, что можно дать определение для `pure virtual function` вне класса:

```
struct Abstract {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void Abstract::foo() { std::cout << "Abstract"; }
```

Является ли такой способ соответствующим стандарту? Можно ли как-то вызвать эту функцию (из наследника или какими-то кастами)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Является. Можно.

Такую функцию можно вызвать при помощи квалифицированного имени

```
struct Derived : Abstract {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Derived"; }
};

...
Derived *p = new Derived;
p->Abstract::foo();

Derived d;
d.Abstract::foo();
```

Точно так же, через квалифицированное имя вы вызываете функции базового класса из одноименных функций классов-наследников (только не обязательно указывая часть `this->`)

```
struct Derived : Abstract {
  virtual void foo() {  
    Abstract::foo(); // то же что и `this->Abstract::foo();`
    std::cout << "Derived"; 
  }
};
```

Также, эквивалентным образом неявно вызываются деструкторы базовых классов из деструкторов классов-наследников. Это означает, что всякий раз, когда вы объявляете деструктор как pure virtual, вам все равно придется предоставить для него определение.